# How to get first N number of elements from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, slice, extract

I am working with Javascript(ES6) /FaceBook react and trying to get the first 3 elements of an array that varies in size. I would like do the equivalent of Linq take(n).

In my Jsx file I have  the following:

```
var items = list.map(i => {
  return (
    <myview item={i} key={i.id} />
  );
});
```

Then to get the first 3 items I tried

```
  var map = new Map(list);
    map.size = 3;
    var items = map(i => {
      return (<SpotlightLandingGlobalInboxItem item={i} key={i.id} />);
    });
```

This didn't work as map doesn't have a set function. What can I try next?

Answer (score 864, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
// ...inside the render() function

var size = 3;
var items = list.slice(0, size).map(i => {
    return <myview item={i} key={i.id} />
});                       
return (
  <div>
    {items}
  </div>   
)
```

Answer (score 1732):

To get the first `n` elements of an array, use

```
const slicedArray = array.slice(0, n);
```

Comment: Note that the `slice` function on arrays returns a shallow copy of the array, and does not modify the original array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Does this throw any error if n is larger than size?

Comment: @Rishabh876 No it does not. For `array.slice(0, n);` it returns `[0, min(n, array.length))`.

Comment: I echo @Rishabh876 Another upped answer which is just incorrect and can be hard to debug at a later point.

Comment: @Morgoth -  I'm confused here -- are you saying this is incorrect because, in cases when the array has less than 3 elements, this method won't return 3 elements?

Comment: @ashleedawg Depends on your definition of correct. If `array` has less than 3 elements and you slice it for 3, then it will return all the elements in the array (i.e. less than 3). That is a very sensible behaviour, but if that does not make sense for your application you might want to check the length of the array first.

Answer (score 89):

```
arr.length = n
```

This might be surprising but `length` property of an array is not only used to get number of array elements but it's also writable and can be used to set array's length [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length). This will mutate the array.

If you don't care about immutability or don't want to allocate memory i.e. for a game this will be the fastest way.

to empty an array

```
arr.length = 0
```

Comment: This will also expand the array if it is smaller than N

Comment: Pawel's answer seems the best option in resource-critical environments, and when the remaining elements can be discarded. Considering the case when the array is already smaller, this is a little improvement: `if (arr.length > n) arr.length = n`

Answer (score 52):

**Use Slice Method**

The javascript `slice()` method returns a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.

syntax : `slice(start, end)`

Let us say we have an array with 7 items `[5,10,15,20,25,30,35]` and we want the first 5 elements from that array:

```
let array = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35]
let newArray = array.slice(0,5)

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: please just pay attention you'll receive the values in the array beginning with the one at index start untill the one at index end - 1. this is good to allow looping.

Answer (score 44):

You can filter using `index` of array.

```js
var months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
months = months.filter((month,idx) => idx < 2)
console.log(months);
```

Comment: `.filter` on it's own is not a great choice, at least not if the input array might be long. `.filter` goes through every element of the array checking its condition. `.slice` would not do this, but would just extract the first n elements and then stop processing - which would definitely be what you want for a long list. (As @elQueFaltaba already said in comments to another answer.)

Answer (score 19):

Do not try doing that using a map function. Map function should be used to map values from one thing to other. When the number of input and output match.

In this case use filter function which is also available on the array. Filter function is used when you want to selectively take values maching certain criteria. Then you can write your code like

```
var items = list
             .filter((i, index) => (index < 3))
             .map((i, index) => {
                   return (
                     <myview item={i} key={i.id} />
                   );
              });
```

Comment: You're correct overall, but semantically you should use filter to *first* filter down the set of elements, then, map the filtered down set if you are taking this approach.

Comment: The filter function would go through all the elements in the array, while the slice would not, so it's better performant-wise to use slice, right?

Answer (score 15):

Just try this to get first `n` elements from list:

```
const slicedList = list.slice(0, n);
```

Example:

```js
const list = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(list.slice(0, 3)) // Should return [1,2,3] 
console.log(list.slice(0, 10)) // Returns [1,2,3,4,5] since this is all we have in 1st 10 elements
```

Answer (score 14):

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8].slice(0, 3) = While return the first 3 elements.

Answer: [1,2,3]

[How it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.

Answer (score 10):

The following worked for me.

```
array.slice( where_to_start_deleting, array.length )
```

Here is an example

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.slice(2, fruits.length);
//Banana,Orange  ->These first two we get as resultant
```

Comment: In the first example you use `slice` but in the second you use `splice`.

Comment: This is also wrong. You will get `["Apple", "Mango"]` from this. The first part of slice is not "where to start deleting", it's where to start the slice from. It doesn't modify the original array and won't delete anything.

Comment: This is not correct. Slice returns a new array of the sliced items. Should be `fruits.slice(0,2)`, where `0` is the starting index and `2` is the number to take. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 7):

With [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#take), `take` function, you can achieve this by following:

```
_.take([1, 2, 3]);
// => [1]
 
_.take([1, 2, 3], 2);
// => [1, 2]
 
_.take([1, 2, 3], 5);
// => [1, 2, 3]
 
_.take([1, 2, 3], 0);
// => []
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a simple example:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var letters_02 = letters.slice(0, 2);
console.log(letters_02)
```

> Output: ["a", "b"]

```
var letters_12 = letters.slice(1, 2);
console.log(letters_12)
```

> Output: ["b"]

Note: `slice` provides only a *shallow* copy and **DOES NOT** modify the original array.

Answer (score 3):

The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.

```
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];

console.log(animals.slice(2));
// expected output: Array ["camel", "duck", "elephant"]

console.log(animals.slice(2, 4));
// expected output: Array ["camel", "duck"]

console.log(animals.slice(1, 5));
// expected output: Array ["bison", "camel", "duck", "elephant"]

console.log(animals.slice(-2));
// expected output: Array ["duck", "elephant"]

console.log(animals.slice(2, -1));
// expected output: Array ["camel", "duck"]
```

[know more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

With [**LInQer**](https://github.com/Siderite/LInQer) you can do:

```
Enumerable.from(list).take(3).toArray();
```