# JavaScript: Find first 3 keys with highest values

Tags: javascript

I'm extremely new to JS, so I'm struggling on how to even ask the question, but here it goes:

I have a dict:
`let x = {a:12,b:5,c:1,d:7,e:10};` Values change but keys remain the same.

I need a way to produce output of highest 3 keys based on their values, something like this:

`let gold = "a"
let silver = "e"
let bronze = "d"`

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Sort descending then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883068/how-to-get-first-n-number-of-elements-from-an-array

Comment: i think that first you better to convert your object to array:Object.keys(obj).map((a)=>({id:a, value:obj[a]})); after you can sort it and select first 3  :
 Object.keys(obj).map((a)=>({id:a, value:obj[a]})).sort((a,b)=>a.value<b.value).slice(0,3)

Comment: @happyZZR1400 - Thank you very, very much, that worked like a charm!