# Javascript Array - get first 10 items

Tags: javascript

I have got a javascript array, and I want to extract the first 10 items from it.
Is this possible to use map method for this?

the code I tried is below:

```
data.map((item, i) => {
  placeIDs.push(item.place_id);
});
```

This code block returns 20 place_ids but I want to have only 10.

So I tried **break** inside the map method, and it says **SyntaxError: Illegal break statement**.

Here **data** is json result from google place api, and it returns 20 results.

One result

```
{
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 61.2180556,
        "lng": -149.9002778
      },
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 61.48393789999999,
          "lng": -148.4600069
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 60.733791,
          "lng": -150.4206149
        }
      }
    },
    "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
    "id": "2edc2d446c844a7a55a2ccbe4a2dfda60a5a0264",
    "name": "Anchorage",
    "photos": [
      {
        "height": 1152,
        "html_attributions": [
          "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102061280252416580615\">Efren Norstein</a>"
        ],
        "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAA9aiV4_BwvK6GfpuswWMBzwuO4LM55YUxGuN8q-4kyZ2-eeyl386ArGmc0-qyBr1r49cuibTIx_2QjFNIBoSRZFspgTBKzciji_-srPClBjNKx8q02BmvwM5vZxVy71lSEhDSY8VwSU2I6uHJPBVvZStBGhQ-_-ZcvP8QhktxugB9k_YHr3OX6A",
        "width": 2048
      }
    ],
    "place_id": "ChIJQT-zBHaRyFYR42iEp1q6fSU",
    "reference": "ChIJQT-zBHaRyFYR42iEp1q6fSU",
    "scope": "GOOGLE",
    "types": ["locality", "political"],
    "vicinity": "Anchorage"
  },
```

**placeIDs** is an array.
I want to extract place_ids from the first 10.

So the main idea is that is it possible to break the map inside it?

Comment: use `data.slice(0,10).map(x => x.place_id)`

Comment: Inside map function add a if condition for getting only 10 records

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first N number of elements from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883068/how-to-get-first-n-number-of-elements-from-an-array)

Comment: Can't I use break inside the map method? Instead of slice~

Comment: @XiaoJin no, `map` does not provide any functionality to _break_.

Comment: not the best approach but filtering data array will work.

placeIDs =  data.filter((val.place_id,idx) => idx < 10)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will do the job. Replace `[startIndex]` and `[endIndex]` with 0 and 10 to get the first 10.

```
data.slice([startIndex], [endIndex]).map((item, i) => {
  placeIDs.push(item.place_id);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at slice https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

E.g. const my10Items = myArray.slice(0, 10);

Answer (score 1):

```
var mapdata = [{ a: "x", b: "y" }, { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: "m", b: "n" }, { a: "aa", b: "bb" }, { a: "11", b: "22" }];
var result = mapdata.splice(0, 3).map(_data => {
                return { a: _data.a };
})
// result is [{"a":"x"},{"a":1},{"a":"m"}]
   or
   var result = mapdata.splice(0, 3).map(_data => {
              return _data.a;
   })
// result is ["x", 1, "m"]
```

Comment: I thought [{a:"x", b:"y"}, {a: 1, b: 2}].

Comment: splice(startIndex, endIndex)