# is there a way to apply map function to a certain array elements reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a large array which i want to apply a function into. normally I use map to apply function for all array elements. but I need to apply function for only first 15 elements of the array . is there a way to do that so i get a certain result
I tried to slice the array then map around it but it didn't work
thanks

Comment: what was the issue with slicing the array? if the array is large then the best approach would be to slice it.

Comment: I think the answer to this question can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883068/how-to-get-first-n-number-of-elements-from-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this one.

```
var items = large_array.slice(0, 15).map(i => {
    return <myview item={i} key={i.id} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change an original array:

```
for (let idx = 0; idx < 15; idx++) {
    array[idx] = mapper(array[idx]);
}
```

Otherwise, version without modifying an original array:

```
array = array.map((item, idx) => idx < 15 ? mapper(item) : item);
```