# Best way to get the first 3 elements looping through an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to get the first 3 elements looping through that React array?

```js
const elements = [
  {id:1, label:"1", value:1},
  {id:2, label:"2", value:2},
  {id:3, label:"3", value:3},
  {id:4, label:"4", value:4},
  {id:5, label:"3", value:5},
  {id:6, label:"3", value:6}
];
```

Comment: array methods, ideally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first N number of elements from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883068/how-to-get-first-n-number-of-elements-from-an-array)

Comment: If below answers are useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If any answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (once the system allows that). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

If it's ok to mutate the original array,

```js
const elements = [
      {id:1, label:"1", value:1},
      {id:2, label:"2", value:2},
      {id:3, label:"3", value:3},
      {id:4, label:"4", value:4},
      {id:5, label:"3", value:5},
      {id:6, label:"3", value:6}
    ];
elements.length = 3;
console.log(elements);
```

If it's ok to mutate the original array but instead of just first 3 or first n elements, you might want to pick a window, splice would give you much more flexibility. [More details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const elements = [
      {id:1, label:"1", value:1},
      {id:2, label:"2", value:2},
      {id:3, label:"3", value:3},
      {id:4, label:"4", value:4},
      {id:5, label:"3", value:5},
      {id:6, label:"3", value:6}
    ];
elements.splice(3);
console.log(elements);
```

If mutating the original array is not desired, then `slice` is your friend. [More details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const elements = [
      {id:1, label:"1", value:1},
      {id:2, label:"2", value:2},
      {id:3, label:"3", value:3},
      {id:4, label:"4", value:4},
      {id:5, label:"3", value:5},
      {id:6, label:"3", value:6}
    ];
const newElements = elements.slice(0, 3);
console.log(newElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your preset needs fixes since it's `key: value` pairs in object, not `key=value`.

But you can use `.slice(start, length)` for getting the certain amount of results:

```js
const elements = [{
    id: 1,
    label: "1",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "2",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: "3",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: "4",
    value: 4
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    label: "3",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    label: "3",
    value: 6
  }
];

console.log(elements.slice(0,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use splice function

```js
const elements = [ 
  {id:1, label:"1", value :1},
  {id:2, label:"2", value :2},
  {id:3, label:"3", value:3},
  {id:4, label:"4", value:4},
  {id:5, label:"3", value:5},
  {id:6, label:"3", value:6}
]

const first_tree=elements.splice(0,3)
console.log(first_tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const elements = [{id:1, label:"1", value:1},{id:2, label:"2", value:2},{id:3, label:"3", value:3},{id:4, label:"4", value:4},{id:5, label:"5", value:5},{id:6, label:"6", value:6}];
const [one, two, three] = elements;
console.log(one, two, three);
```

Or [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
{elements.slice(0, 3).map((item) => (
  <div key={item.id}>{item.label}</div>
))}
```