# Sort hashmap descending by value and limit it to 10 records javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, hashmap

I need to sort this from highest to lowest and limit the number of records to 10 with highest values, I'm not good with programming and couldn't find similar examples.
Any tips regarding code would also be appreciated<33

```
function getMostFrequent(arr) {
  const hashmap = arr.reduce( (acc, val) => {
   acc[val] = (acc[val] || 0 ) + 1
   return acc
},{})
return Object.entries(hashmap).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
}

console.log(getMostFrequent(output));
```

this is the output I get

```
[
  [ '300', 173 ], [ '200', 31 ], [ '500', 31 ],
  [ '800', 29 ],  [ '700', 28 ], [ '600', 26 ],
  [ '400', 20 ],  [ '290', 11 ], [ '160', 10 ],
  [ '220', 10 ],  [ '250', 9 ],  [ '100', 8 ],
  [ '240', 8 ],   [ '260', 8 ],  [ '350', 8 ],
  [ '370', 8 ],   [ '230', 7 ],  [ '390', 7 ],
  [ '210', 6 ],   [ '280', 6 ],  [ '110', 5 ],
  [ '140', 5 ],   [ '150', 5 ],  [ '270', 5 ],
  [ '310', 5 ],   [ '320', 5 ],  [ '120', 4 ],
  [ '130', 4 ],   [ '330', 4 ],  [ '340', 4 ],
  [ '170', 3 ],   [ '190', 3 ],  [ '360', 2 ],
  [ '380', 2 ],   [ '', 1 ]
]
```

Comment: Can you please copy&paste the content of the hashmap as text in to the question so that we can use it to debug the code. Images of code are useless.

Comment: It looks like you sorted it already.  So you just need the first 10 entries?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883068/how-to-get-first-n-number-of-elements-from-an-array

Comment: DO NOT SORT HASHMAP VALUES! It screws up the lookup

Comment: If you want a sorted map, use a TreeMap

Comment: He's not sorting an object.  He's sorting Object.entries(thatObject), which is an array.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'm pretty sure the OP is mixing terminology, which is why I asked for the actual content to be added to the question.

Comment: @James, I'm not sure, I'd like for the values to go from biggest to smallest but I'll look into the linked question so I can get the first 10 entries, thank you :))

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I might be mixing terminology, you're right ^^", I'll paste it as text when I get home, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

@James was right, thank you so much<33 after implementing

```
var top10 = getMostFrequent(output).slice(0,10)
```

I got the correct answer, thanks everyone for your help :)!!