# How to show only 10 items from the list of object in a dataset in Reacct

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display **only 10 list items** from the property name ***"text"*** which is in one of a dataset object and give more button below that. On this button click I want to show remaining list items. I tried with the below code using useState hook but not getting the desired result, I know I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ReadMoreReadLess = ({ children }) => {

  const [ReadMoreShown, setReadMoreShown] = useState(false);

  const toggleBtn = () => {
    setReadMoreShown(prevState => !prevState)
  }

  return (
    <div className='readMore_readLess'>
      {children}
      <button onClick={toggleBtn}>Read More</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ReadMoreReadLess
```

Below is one of the dataset object

```
const data = [
{
  type: "Names",
  text: [
    {id: "1", info: "Audi"},
    {id: "2", info: "BMW"},
    {id: "3", info: "Chevrolet"},
    {id: "4", info: "Citroen"},
    {id: "5", info: "Hyundai"},
    {id: "6", info: "Mercedes-Benz"},
    {id: "7", info: "Renault"},
    {id: "8", info: "Seat"},
    {id: "9", info: "KIA"},
    {id: "10", info: "Toyota"},
  ],
  image: service_1,
},];
```

I'm displaying like this.

```
<div className="services__service__description">
  <ReadMoreReadLess>
   {text.map((t) => (
    <ul>
      <li key={t.id}>
        {t.info}
      </li>
    </ul>                      
   ))}
  </ReadMoreReadLess>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first N number of elements from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883068/how-to-get-first-n-number-of-elements-from-an-array)

Comment: Ohh yeah! It is... with some changes I acheived the required result. Thank you so much indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this changes to my code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ReadMoreReadLess = ({ children }) => {

  const [isReadMoreShown, setReadMoreShown] = useState(false);

  const toggleBtn = () => {
    setReadMoreShown((prevState) => !prevState)
  }

  return (
    <div className='readMore_readLess'>
      {isReadMoreShown ? children : children.slice(0, 5)}
      <button onClick={toggleBtn}>Read More</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ReadMoreReadLess
```

Displaying it like this

```
<div className="services__service__description">
  <ReadMoreReadLess>
    {text.map((t) => (
      <ul>
        <li key={t.id}>
          {t.info}
        </li>
      </ul>                      
    ))}
  </ReadMoreReadLess>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.current_page` equals 0 initially then get changed when you want to show more items

```
<div className="services__service__description">
  <ReadMoreReadLess>
   {text.slice(0, (this.state.current_page+1)*10).map((t) => (
    <ul>
      <li key={t.id}>
        {t.info}
      </li>
    </ul>                      
   ))}
  </ReadMoreReadLess>
</div>
```